# This bundle is invalid .The Info.plist file for /Payload/XXX.app/Sticker Pack.stickerpack is missing or could not be read

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store-connect, ipa

I added an IOS Sticker extension for my project developed in Cordova. For this extension I added all required images and icons. I tested in the simulator and real device and it is working. Then, I try to upload to itunes. The app has a bundle identifier com.XXX.YYY and the extesion is com.XXX.YYY.Stickers, both have provision profile signed with the same certificate. When I upload de IPA to Store I recieve an email from Itunes with this error;

`This bundle is invalid . The Info.plist file for /Payload/XXX.app/Sticker Pack.stickerpack is missing or could not be read.`

I renamed the ipa file for zip and opened it.

[zip opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf4fZ.png)

then Show Packages in **Payload/XXX**

[ShowPackagesPayload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq0lE.png)

The info.plist doesn´t appear but I dont know if it´s OK

I used Xcode 8.3.1 to build my IPA. I tested in a Iphone 6 with 10.3

Any ideas? Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the XCode version (8.3.1).
With 8.3.3 it works ok!